# One way diff between 2 directories

Tags: directory, diff, recursive

I am looking to perform a diff between 2 directories, both of which contain may files and subdirectories.

I am hoping to perform a one-way diff between a source and target directory that will return only the following:

1. Files that exist in source but not in target
2. Files that have changes in source that do not exist in target

So this would exclude:

1. Files that exist in the target but not in the source
2. Any additions that have been made to files in the target directory that do not conflict with a line in the source
3. Any changes related to whitespace

Is this possible? 
I am using Cygwin.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'Any additions that have been made to files in the target directory that do not conflict with a line in the source'?

Comment: Your question isn't too clear. Can you elaborate on your criteria and your expected output?